# What Eclipse view will let me paste random text in it?

Tags: eclipse

There seems to be no view in Eclipse where I could paste (edit: *and view in their entirety*) assorted chunks of text. Does anyone know of one?

Thank you.

Comment: The problem here is, that eclipse uses editors for editing (anything) and views for viewing anything. Some are in between, so there are lists of values you may edit inline. You should add some examples what you want to paste, and how to view it.

Comment: It makes sense. Can you view two editors at the same time then? Aside from the quickdiff mode.

Comment: Yes of course. Just open two editors, and drag one of them (the tab of the editor) to the right. Eclipse visualizes that there may be another region for editors there.

Comment: Magic! You can even have three and all. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to do ?

If you want to paste a snippet of code you can use the Snippet View : `Window -> Show View -> Snippets`

Comment: Nice feature, I'll use it for sure for templates. But it won't let me view its contents on the go (just updated my question sorry)